# Property not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to give my `h1` tag a value that i retrieve from my Firestore database. however i keep getting this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null ... I dont know why i get this.

In my wait.html i gave h1 the `id="idnumberwaiting"` . Then in the same file I linked my javascript script.

Then in my JS script i tried this:

```js
document.getElementById("idnumberwaiting").innerHTML = roomIDD
```

I think I've done everything right...

However, the playButton where I added the addEventListener is in a separate html. So basically all I am trying to do is in `home.html` where my playButton is located, I want to press that button and I want then to change to the `wait.html` page and there load the value from the Firebase.

**This is my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wait.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><a href="home.html">Rock Paper Scissors</a></header>
    <div class="result">
        <p id="pharagraph">Waiting for your opponent to join.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="choices">
            <div id="ch1" class="choice">
                <p class="lablechoice">ROOM ID</p>
                <h1 id="idnumberwaiting" class="lablechoice">13798</h1> 
                <div class="lds-ripple"><div></div><div></div></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my JS code where I try to give it the value:**

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var roomIDD = roomID();
    db.collection('game').add({
        playerone : document.getElementById("nameinput").value ,
        playeronechoice : "",
        players : 1,
        playertwo : "",
        playertwochoice : "",
        roomid : roomIDD,
        scoreone : 0,
        scoretwo : 0
    }).then(function(){
        document.getElementById("idnumberwaiting").innerHTML = roomIDD.toString;
        setTimeout(function(){location.replace("wait.html");},2000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your element with id `nameinput`? I cannot find it from your code posted :-?

Comment: Hello Mara, that is also in the other html file, together with the playButton